# Rails PhantomJS for scraping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, phantomjs, watir, watir-webdriver

I am new to rails and have never use angular js. I want to extract price and seller name from this link [link](https://paytm.com/shop/p/gionee-e7-mini-black-MOBGIONEE-E7-MIHAPP44414CBBDB36C?psearch=organic%7Cundefined%7Cgionee%20e7%7Cgrid)

```
module HomesHelper
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'phantomjs'
require 'watir'

b = Watir::Browser.new(:phantomjs)

b.goto url
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(b.html)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add `Nokogiri` or `mechanize` here. `watir` will get all element you want. Try run below code, It will solve your issue.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'phantomjs'
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
browser.window.maximize
browser.goto "https://paytm.com/shop/p/gionee-e7-mini-black-MOBGIONEE-E7-MIHAPP44414CBBDB36C?psearch=organic|undefined|gionee%20e7|grid"
puts browser.div(:class => 'profile-description').a.h2.text
puts browser.div(:class => 'buy-bar').button.span.text
puts browser.div(:class => 'effPrc').span.text
browser.close
```

Comment: Hey i pasted the code it is showing an error undefined method `maximiz' for #<Watir::Window:0x75dcffacef69afd4 located=true>

Comment: Ok jjust change it with `browser.window.maximize` I forgot e there :)

Comment: Try remove phantomjs from `browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs` and change to `browser = Watir::Browser.new` it will open your browser. See if site is loading in mobile view or not

Comment: site is opening but now getting this error end of file reached

Comment: I have tested it and it working fine for me. [DEPRECATION] requiring "RMagick" is deprecated. Use "rmagick" instead
Happy deals
Buy for Rs 9,499
Rs. 22,799 | 58% Discount

Comment: Which was given from also available from sellers

Comment: It's in ul and li tag and both work similar to h2 tag in my code. Try change some code there and you are done :)